# Is there way to get repository conflict notifications in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I've just realized that I can schedule synchronization of my repository in Eclipse.  However, it would be nice if I got notified of conflicts without having to go the the "Team Synchronizing" perspective to see it.  Is there a summary view or a way to have a pop-up show?

Basically I want to know as soon as possible that there is a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think its possible with the current svn eclipse plugin because in order to show your file conflict it has to connect to the svn server automatically and do a file compare every time you press save on the file which is network consuming.

Comment: Not saying it would have to check each time I save, but would be nice to know once the conflict is detected, that the file would be flagged in my regular perspective, like a standard Eclipse warning.